# First item of card carousel

Tags: wordpress, elementor

don't have a specific code to post here, cuz I'm doing stuff on elementor wordpress, but there is Unlimited Elements plugin card carousel that's in tab, and I need the carousel to scroll to the first item when the tab is clicked, sorry for complicated question and not providing the code, I'm just wondering if there is any posibility to do that? thanks in advance

I tried scrollTo function also scrollToLeft and the other but nothing works